# Longclick on TextView causes disappearance of appbar

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a TextView, it is scrollable but not clickable either copy/pasteable. It contains a long text, that is why I use scrollbars. When I scroll down to read further, and do a longclick on the textview my appbar "dissappears" See the two pictures before longclick and after longlick. How can I solve this really annoying problem?

[image: Before longclick]

[image: After longclick on TextView]

here is my xml for this layout:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textfrag10label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Kneten"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#FFFF4444"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textfrag10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:maxLines="25"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:text="very long text"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textfrag10label"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by deleting `android:textIsSelectable="true"`